# Changing the bits in an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of bits. Bits will be toggled off and on according to following criteria:
1. if the bits left and right of bit is on put the bit to one otherwise zero.
2. boundary condition(leftmost and rightmost bit will only depend on one bit. ie either left of it or right of it.

this array will be processed m times with the following criteria.

I wrote the following code where A is the original array and subsiquent is the array for processing. But this will give me O(nm) where n is the length and m is no of times i want to do the process. Please suggest me some alternative for the solution so that i can decrease my complexity.

```
for(int k = 0;k < m;k++){
  for(int l = 0;l < n;k++){
    if(l == 0){
      if(A[l+1]==1)
        subsiquent[l]=1;
      else
        subsiquent[l]=0;
      //** is there a } missing here?
      else if(l==n){
        if(A[l-1]==1)
          subsiquent[l]=1;
        else
          subsiquent[l]=0;                        
      } else {
        if(A[l+1]==1 && A[l-1]==1 ){
          subsiquent[l]=1;
        }else{
          subsiquent[l]=0;
        }
      } 
    //** or is there a } missing here?      
  }

  A = subsiquent;
}
```

Comment: You want to scan `n` bits `m` times? I'd doubt that the complexity can be reduced significantly below O(n*m).

Comment: So do u suggest there can be no alternative solution to toggle up. Can't any thing be done for toggling other than scanning it m times? Thanks

Comment: @ketananand Why do you want to scan it m times?

Comment: if I had to do 1 time the solution would be simple and just by doing a lazy update I would have toggled up the whole array. and complexity would be O(n). but if I had to do it m times can there will be a better method than this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to do this m times? If I understand your explanation and code correctly 1110100 would become 1101000 after one iteration, 1000000 after 2 iterations and 0000000 after 3 iterations. Is that what you want? And what would that mean to you?

Comment: Btw, I reformatted your code a bit and added 2 comments since there is a closing brace missing but I'm not sure where (I guess at the location of the first comment). Also, you should try and either always use braces for 1-statement blocks (I recommend that) or never (not recommended), otherwise your code can contain hard to spot bugs due to confusion on which block a statement belongs to. Finally, in your inner loop you're incrementing `k` instead of the `l` you're using which would result in an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to see:

- If your last p first or p last bits are 0, they will always stay 0, and so will bit p+1 (resp. p-1) . So you can add a check on this, and reduce the start / end of your l loop (and change p+1 digit to 0)
- Similaraly, if p first (resp last) digits are 1, then p-1 digits will stay at 1 andbit p will be 0
- I you have all zero or all 1, no more changed are needed
- the same thing can be done in the middle of your array (5 zero in the middle? There will  be 7 next time. Five 1? The three middle will stay 1), but not sure it's easy to integrate (only if you have say 1000 same bit is it worth dealing with it I think)
- If you don't end to all 0 or all 1, you will have an alternate of 0 and 1. So you can also check if ou are alternating 0 and 1, and with a modulo 2 on remaining m, you can predict the result

Edit: with p>=2 in my examples for extremities of course

Edit: you can represent your array as the number of similar bits in an int array + memorizing the first bit
`000111101100110101` would be represented as [0]3412221111 (begin with zero, then 3 zero, then 4 one, then 1 zero, then 2 one, etc.)

I didn't check all, but you can infer the rule to go from one step to an other rather easily with minimum step. (there are many cases, I let you find them. You only have to go from left to right and remember that you switch from 0 and 1, but may have to modify/decrease the number on the right when iterating, or inserting number. A linked list will be well suited here)

For example, the steps will be:

```
000111101100110101  [0]3-4-1-2-2-2-1-1-1-1      
000011010000001010  [0]4-2-1-1-6-1-1-1-1
000000100000000101  [0]6-1-8-1-1-1
000000000000000010  [0]16-1-1
000000000000000001  [0]17-1
000000000000000000  [0]18
```

Comment: Thanks for the help